# How to convert substring of bits in ip address into decimal numbers?

Tags: java, java-7

I have a substring of bits in ip address like,

```
    System.out.println("1 MSB: " + binaryForm.substring(0, 1));//1
    System.out.println("6 bits: " + binaryForm.substring(1, 7));//010101
    System.out.println("25 LSB: " + binaryForm.substring(7));//: 1101010000110010000010111
```

How to convert 6 bits into one decimal number and 25 bits into an other decimal number?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Integer.parseInt(str, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Integer.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a radix of 2.